# How to do logging in ASP.NET Web Application on Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm really confused about how to setup logging and view the logs with Azure.

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that I have deployed to the cloud, but I'm not having much luck configuring or setting up logging for Azure.

There is a lot of information about Azure Diagnostics, Worker Roles etc., but I'm not clear how they even relate to an ASP.NET Web Application.

Does anyone know of a simple (Up to Date) tutorial for just being able to write and view logs for an ASP.NET application in Azure.

It's been a little while since I've worked with ASP.NET and working with Azure is really confusing.

[image]

Comment: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api

This should help you

Comment: Are you deploying to Azure Websites or Cloud Services (web role)?

Comment: @BenV, this is where I"m a bit confused about the whole thing, I assume I'm deploying Azure Websites, but what I've got is an Asp.NET application that I am publishing to an Azure Website.

Comment: Then the first link from @NikiteshKolpe should be all you need.  Logging in Azure Websites is simple (essentially just `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Tracexxx()`).  Cloud Services are more complicated.

Comment: Thanks @NikiteshKolpe and Ben, that first link is providing the information I needed, plus its a new day and my mind is fresh